# Rotacionar spans na LI

Tags: html, css, css3

Tenho o **código** abaixo que funciona normalmente.

Mas contém uma falha.

Se notarem, a *primeira* e a *terceira* **div's** estão sem **class**. Isso quer dizer que *não quero* rotacionar seus **spans**.

Mas, não rotacionando, esses **2** **spans** *saem* da **li**.

O que fazer para corrigir isso?

```css
span.vertical {
transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(270deg);
}

div.cabecalhoVertical {
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
flex-wrap: nowrap;
width: 100%;
height: 200px;
align-items: center;
border: .1px rgb(0, 0, 0) solid;
}

div.cabecalhoVertical div {
position: relative;
height: 100%;
flex-grow: 1;
border-left: .1px rgb(0, 0, 0) solid;
}

div.cabecalhoVertical div span {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class='cabecalhoVertical'>
 <div style='width:100px;'><span class=''        >Passo 1</span></div>
 <div style='width:100px;'><span class='vertical'>Passo 2</span></div>
 <div style='width:100px;'><span class=''        >Passo 3</span></div>
 <div style='width:050px;'><span class='vertical'>Passo 4</span></div>
 <div style='width:050px;'><span class='vertical'>Passo 5</span></div>
 <div style='width:050px;'><span class='vertical'>Passo 6</span></div>
 <div style='width:050px;'><span class='vertical'>Passo 7</span></div>
 <div style='width:050px;'><span class='vertical'>Passo 8</span></div>
 <div style='width:050px;'><span class='vertical'>Passo 9</span></div>
 <div style='width:050px;'><span class='vertical'>Passo 10</span></div>
 <div style='width:050px;'><span class='vertical'>Passo 11</span></div>
 <div style='width:050px;'><span class='vertical'>Passo 12</span></div>
 <div style='width:050px;'><span class='vertical'>Passo 13</span></div>
</div>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crie um bloco de propriedades para os spans que não possuem a classe `.vertical`, ajustando ao centro da `li`. Repare que algumas propriedades declaradas nesse novo bloco não precisam ser repetidas no bloco da classe `.vertical`, pois já valem para todos os spans):

```
div.cabecalhoVertical div span{
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   text-align: center;
   display: inline-block;
   width: 100%;
   height: 20px;
   margin-top: -10px;
}
```

```css
span.vertical {
transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(270deg);
}

div.cabecalhoVertical {
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
flex-wrap: nowrap;
width: 100%;
height: 200px;
align-items: center;
border: .1px rgb(0, 0, 0) solid;
}

div.cabecalhoVertical div {
position: relative;
height: 100%;
flex-grow: 1;
border-left: .1px rgb(0, 0, 0) solid;
}

div.cabecalhoVertical div span{
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   text-align: center;
   display: inline-block;
   width: 100%;
   height: 20px;
   margin-top: -10px;
}

div.cabecalhoVertical div span.vertical {
width: 200px;
height: auto;
background: red; /* retire essa linha*/
left: 50%;
top: 55%;
}
```

```html
<div class='cabecalhoVertical'>
 <div style='width:100px;'><span class=''        >Passo 1</span></div>
 <div style='width:100px;'><span class='vertical'>Passo 2</span></div>
 <div style='width:100px;'><span class=''        >Passo 3</span></div>
 <div style='width:050px;'><span class='vertical'>Passo 4</span></div>
 <div style='width:050px;'><span class='vertical'>Passo 5</span></div>
 <div style='width:050px;'><span class='vertical'>Passo 6</span></div>
 <div style='width:050px;'><span class='vertical'>Passo 7</span></div>
 <div style='width:050px;'><span class='vertical'>Passo 8</span></div>
 <div style='width:050px;'><span class='vertical'>Passo 9</span></div>
 <div style='width:050px;'><span class='vertical'>Passo 10</span></div>
 <div style='width:050px;'><span class='vertical'>Passo 11</span></div>
 <div style='width:050px;'><span class='vertical'>Passo 12</span></div>
 <div style='width:050px;'><span class='vertical'>Passo 13</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: tem como aumentar o espaço das spans para caber o Passo 13 inteiro em um linha só?Porque terá palavas maires que essa

Comment: Resposta atualizada. Veja que coloquei um fundo vermelho para pode visualizar o tamanho do span, aí vc apaga do código CSS o background: red

Comment: Olha, eu estiou aceitando a tua resposta pois foi show. Mas se não for pedir demai, tem como colocar um exemplo idêntico mas ao invés de ser com divs ser com ul? Fui tentar mas com UL fica dando tipo uma coluna à mais do lado esquerdo que não consigo tirar

Comment: Acho que eh possível. Mas só vou poder ver isso mais tarde pq estou fazendo uma manutenção na máquina

Comment: Opa, sem problemas. Espero com prazer. Aprender com quem sabe? Não tem preço.

Comment: Taí o código: https://jsfiddle.net/gk2oL6a7/